# How to force joi to invoke custom function when the object schema is invalid?

Tags: javascript, joi

I create in my [Joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0) schema a custom function to validate if name is `equal` to `confirmName`.

And I use `abortEarly: false` to get all the errors.

The problem is the when validation failed in the `object` the `custom` function not invoke.

currently the results output is just for `birthYear`. it should be `birthYear` and `custom` .

Is there a way to make it work as I describe?

```
{ name: "foo", confirmName: "oo", birthYear: 0 },
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-water-zx22k?file=/src/index.js:0-561)

```
const Joi = require("joi");

console.clear();

const schema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string(),
  confirmName: Joi.string(),
  birthYear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013)
}).custom((doc, helpers) => {
  const { name, confirmName } = doc;
  if (name !== confirmName) {
    throw new Error("name not match!!");
  }
});

const { error } = schema.validate(
  { name: "foo", confirmName: "oo", birthYear: 0 },
  { allowUnknown: true, abortEarly: false }
);

console.log({ error });

if (error) {
  const { details } = error;
  console.log({ details });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom validation to make sure `name` is equal to `confirmName`.

Just use a [reference to the value](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#refkey-options):

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string(),
  confirmName: Joi.ref('name'),
  birthYear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013)
});
```

And if you want to override the error message, you can use [.messages](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anymessagesmessages):

```
confirmName: Joi.string().required()
                         .valid(Joi.ref('name'))
                         .messages({'any.only': 'name not match!!'})
```